# How do you define your own parameters in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently trying to figure out what percentage of my hourly views have a Visit Duration of 00:00:00.

It's easy enough to create an Advanced Segment for views of '0 seconds' and compare that to my total views - what I'd like to know is: can you combine these two segments, to create a parameter which is '#total-views / #0-sec-views'? And, if so, how?

In other words, how can I define my own parameter which tells me how many of my views lasted for 0 seconds?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

Zetland, just select both segments:

- your custom segment for 0s visits
- pre-defined segment for *All Visits*

Tick both and you should see the comparison, even with percentage difference right in the table below the chart.

One more suggestion: 0s visit is a very unusual segment, as it tracks visits that didn't include more than 2 pageviews (hence the time-difference couldn't be measured). I would suggest using Bounce Visits or Non-converters (or anything similar).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Petr. You're correct - however, I have an event-tracking system on my website which updates whenever a user is active every 15 seconds. Thus, by monitoring 0s visits, I can accurately tell how many people stayed for less than 15 seconds in total.

Also, although your method works for days, I'm really looking for something which will supply me with hourly data. That's why I wanted to know whether I could create my own parameter. There are also other parameters I'd like to create (i.e. bounce rate * number of visits).